# External link warnings

Tags: website-design, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [External links: Whether & how to distinguishing them from internal links, and to open them](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/external-links-whether-how-to-distinguishing-them-from-internal-links-and-to)

What would be the best method of warning a user that the link they are about to click on is external?

The obvious ways I could think of would be;

- Modal pop up when link is clicked
- Warning text on hover
- Text/images next to link

Not keen on the first two, pop ups are very obtrusive and using hover functionality in this context seems extremely inaccessible.