# How to best show links that are internal

Tags: menu, hyperlinks

I have created a wordpress site recently for my club. I have come recently to a discussion about the way I have shown the list of useful links internal to the site.

I have put them under the header "Useful Links" which sounded rather obvious. Someone made me notice that with "Links" people may consider content that is external to the site (so not a page or post on my club's site).

It has to be noted that for the time being there are no external links but there may well be in the future.

While this is not a question of massive importance (no money or contracts involved) it still made me thinking and wanted to ask a bigger audience.

I have seen the similar question ([External links: Whether & how to distinguishing them from internal links, and to open them](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/external-links-whether-how-to-distinguishing-them-from-internal-links-and-to)): this is not about links in a paragraphs or individual links in a menu, but more about how to title the whole menu if it's made up exclusively of internal links (and whether the word "link" in itself conveys the meaning of an external page).

Comment: Is the difference between external and internal really not clear right now on  your site? Could you provide a screenshot perhaps, to clarify things?

Comment: I can provide a link, but the question is more about the general idea about wording the header for this set of links rather than this specific example. Anyway the site is: http://www.dundeesailingclub.org.uk/ (links on right)

Comment: What kind of links are the internal ones?  Administrative? Featured content?  FAQ pages?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the solution here is not to emphasise whether the links are internal or external but to properly categorise the content and purpose of the link targets.

"Useful Links" is too broad to give the user any real clue as to why they should look there. Also, in my experience, areas that lack proper definition in a website soon become dumping grounds for anything that the person maintaining the site can't be bothered to properly classify.

I'd suggest that you probably need to go back and rethink your site map to find a better, more definite, way to categorise the pages that you think you want to add to "Useful Links"

Answer (score 0):

These symbols are fairly standard across the internet, obviously hover is an issue for touch - I don't know whether this is a consideration for you?

[image: External/Internal Links]

Comment: I have considered this, but the question is more about how to categorise the whole menu (meaning which title) to give a better idea that the links are internal. At the moment the title of the list of links is simply "Useful Links" which may bring people to think they are outside the website...

Comment: Menus should be logical to the content, which considers internal and external, but is driven by the flow of your website. It may help to create a website map so you can see where links logically sit.